# Using Sass with Cakephp 3.0

Tags: php, cakephp, sass, cakephp-3.0, compass

I'm new to sass and want to use it for my current cake php 3.0 project. I have looked at tutorials on it and they are for older versions.
I looked at this:

http://mindthecode.com/using-sass-in-your-next-cakephp-project/

In cakephp 3.0, the directory layout is different so I did the config file like this:

```
http_path = "/"  
sass_dir = 'src'                    
css_dir = '../webroot/css'
images_dir = '../webroot/img'
javascripts_dir = '../webroot/js'
http_stylesheets_path = 'css'
http_javascripts_path = 'js'
http_images_path = 'images'
environment = :development
output_style = :compressed
```

instead of this:

```
http_path = "/"
sass_dir = 'src'
css_dir = '../app/webroot/css'
images_dir = '../app/webroot/img'
javascripts_dir = '../app/webroot/js'
http_stylesheets\_path = 'css'
http_javascripts\_path = 'js'
http_images\_path = 'img'
environment = :development
output_style = :compressed
```

when I do the compass watch comand and edit a sass file, its not compiling into a css file in the css directory of my project.

Comment: Is it not compiling at all or compiling the files to the wrong location?

Comment: I just had a look around. Its not compiling at all.

Comment: It's showing the files being modified when its being watched.

Comment: Try using `compass compile` instead and see what happens?  Compass has been known to not properly recompile files on occasion when they update.

Comment: It keeps saying Individual stylesheets must be in the sass directory and when I do compass init it just says no files to compile even when I'm in a sass directory.

Comment: You have to run the command (`compass compile`/`compass watch`) from the same directory as your config.rb

Comment: Okay thank you. That helped. I had to do: gem uninstall listen -v 1.0.3
gem install listen -v 0.7.3 for it to work and now its in a different folder to my css but its now working.

Comment: Why not just using AssetCompress plugin? Its supereasy, live example here: http://sandbox3.dereuromark.de/sandbox/asset-compress-examples It auto-compiles it for you if the files change.